# Displaying the full text instead of post title

Tags: options

I've installed recently WordPress (I guess it should be 3.0? cannot find easily the version number) and my first post appears only the title (linked) and to see the full text one must click the title.

Is there a setting for displaying the full text of a post instead of the title?

Comment: WordPress version is displayed in bottom right of admin screen. Please provide some details - are you using default theme? Had you installed any plugins? Is it first post only?

Answer (score 1):

Try to see inside your index.php file. If it have `<?php the_content(); ?>` inside the loop. Also watch inside your post in admin and don't put any `<!--more-->` tags inside your content. This method show all the content on the main page.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a case of being WP3.0 and you're really new to Wordpress in general, you're going to have fun poking through loop.php which will hold the loop being used, unlike what the first two have said. They are right though in that it's a case of the_excerpt vs the_content. Not sure why it's displaying like that by default with posts instead of the_content, unless it's set that way with the posts.

Just a fyi, the version number can be seen at the bottom of the admin area, in its footer on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find what is called [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). It startes a little bit like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

and finishes like:

```
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

In between these two points, you can include any number of [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags). These tags tell wordress which parts of the post you would like to see, examples include [the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), [the_content()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content), [the_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) and [the_date()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date). These will print that data to the loop.

In this instance, you need to find the loop that is displaying your titles (if it as untouched installation, and you are on the front page, probably the index.php from within your theme folder), find the opening line of the loop and slot in the line . This will display all of the content of the post. If this proves too much for that page, you can change it to